# Can't get custom ASP.NET MembershipProvider to initialize

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, membership

I created a custom MembershipProvider in my ASP.NET Web Application using code I found on MSDN which overrides the "stock" MembershipProvider, since I can't use the aspnet_regsql utility due to database issues with my hosting company.
The following snippet is from the `Initialize` function:

```
        public override void Initialize ( string name, NameValueCollection config ) {
            if ( config == null )
                throw new ArgumentNullException ( "config" );
             if ( name == null || name.Length == 0 )
                name = "SiteUserProvider";
             if ( String.IsNullOrEmpty ( config ["description"] ) ) {
                config.Remove ( "description" );
                config.Add ( "description", "Pueblo411.com Custom Membership provider" );
            }

            base.Initialize ( name, config );
            pApplicationName = GetConfigValue ( config ["applicationName"], HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath );
            pMaxInvalidPasswordAttempts = Convert.ToInt32 ( GetConfigValue ( config ["maxInvalidPasswordAttempts"], "5" ) );
            pPasswordAttemptWindow = Convert.ToInt32 ( GetConfigValue ( config ["passwordAttemptWindow"], "10" ) );
            pMinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters = Convert.ToInt32 ( GetConfigValue ( config ["minRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters"], "1" ) );
            pMinRequiredPasswordLength = Convert.ToInt32 ( GetConfigValue ( config ["minRequiredPasswordLength"], "7" ) );
            pPasswordStrengthRegularExpression = Convert.ToString ( GetConfigValue ( config ["passwordStrengthRegularExpression"], "" ) );
            pEnablePasswordReset = Convert.ToBoolean ( GetConfigValue ( config ["enablePasswordReset"], "true" ) );
            pEnablePasswordRetrieval = Convert.ToBoolean ( GetConfigValue ( config ["enablePasswordRetrieval"], "true" ) );
            pRequiresQuestionAndAnswer = Convert.ToBoolean ( GetConfigValue ( config ["requiresQuestionAndAnswer"], "false" ) );
            pRequiresUniqueEmail = Convert.ToBoolean ( GetConfigValue ( config ["requiresUniqueEmail"], "true" ) );
            connectionString = GetConfigValue ( config ["connectionStringName"], "p411" );
            string temp_format = config["passwordFormat"];
            ConnectionStringSettings ConnectionStringSettings =ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[config["connectionStringName"]];
            if ( ConnectionStringSettings == null || ConnectionStringSettings.ConnectionString.Trim ( ) == "" ) 
                throw new ProviderException ( "Connection string cannot be blank." );
            connectionString = ConnectionStringSettings.ConnectionString;
            Configuration cfg =WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath);
            machineKey = ( MachineKeySection ) cfg.GetSection ( "system.web/machineKey" );
            if ( machineKey.ValidationKey.Contains ( "AutoGenerate" ) )
                if ( PasswordFormat != MembershipPasswordFormat.Clear )
                    throw new ProviderException ( "Hashed or Encrypted passwords are not supported with auto-generated keys." );
        }
```

Everything compiles just fine, but when I try to call `CreateUser`, I get an error saying that the connection string hasn't been initialized.  I tested to see if the connection string variable was being populated, but it turns out that the `Initialize` function isn't even firing.  Here's how I'm using the custom provider in my page to call `CreateUser`

```
                var provider = new SiteUserProvider();
                MembershipUser newUser = provider.CreateUser(uname.Value, psw.Value,email.Value,null,null,false,Guid.NewGuid(), out MembershipCreateStatus status);
```

I don't understand why the `Initialize` method isn't being fired.  Any ideas?